# Importing Excel File To SQL With C# Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to import excel file with 3000 rows into MS SQL Server Database, i am using C# with entity framework, thing is operation takes too long about 15- 20 minutes. 
Am i doing something wrong or is this normal?

Here is foreach loop from my code where paths is path to excel file:

```
            foreach (var item in paths)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(item.Value);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
                try
                {

                    int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                    int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

                    string GenDateString = xlRange.Cells[3, 6].Value2.ToString();
                    string GenDate = GenDateString.Substring(0, 10);
                    string Client = xlRange.Cells[3, 1].Value2.ToString();
                    string User = xlRange.Cells[3, 2].Value2.ToString();
                    string error;
                    if (IsCorrectDate(item.Key, xlRange))
                    {
                        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                        Import import = new Import()
                        {
                            Month = month,
                            year = year,
                            EndDate = item.Key[1],
                            GenerateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(GenDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", provider),
                            StartDate = item.Key[0],
                            FileName = item.Value.ToString()
                        };
                        if (db.Imports.Any(i => i.StartDate == import.StartDate || i.EndDate == import.EndDate))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                progressbar.ReleaseBar();
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                            }
                            SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("ასეთი ფაილი უკვე შეიმპორტებულია", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
                            //cleanup
                            GC.Collect();
                            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                            //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
                            //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
                            //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

                            //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

                            //close and release
                            xlWorkbook.Close();
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

                            //quit and release
                            xlApp.Quit();
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                            return;
                        }
                        for (int i = 8; i <= rowCount; i++)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(i);
                            var bpCode = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
                            if (bpCode == "რეპორტის დასასრული")
                                break;
                            i++;
                            Mediator mediator = new Mediator()
                            {
                                BPCode = bpCode,
                                Import = import,
                            };

                            for (int j = 0; j < clicks.Count(); j++)
                            {
                                progressbar.Up();
                                rowsc--;
                                var clickName = xlRange.Cells[i + j, 1].Value2.ToString();
                                Statistic SmeStatistic = new Statistic()
                                {
                                    ClickNameID = clicks.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == clickName).ID,
                                    ReqPerson = int.Parse(xlRange.Cells[i + j, 2].Value2.ToString()),
                                    ReqBussiness = int.Parse(xlRange.Cells[i + j, 3].Value2.ToString()),
                                    ResPerson = int.Parse(xlRange.Cells[i + j, 5].Value2.ToString()),
                                    ResBussiness = int.Parse(xlRange.Cells[i + j, 6].Value2.ToString()),
                                    Mediator = mediator,
                                };
                                //var xxx = clicks.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == clickName).ID;
                                db.Statistics.Add(SmeStatistic);

                            }
                            i += clicks.Count() - 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //int iReturnValue = SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(item.Value + " ფაილის თარიღი არასწორია.", 1, "&Ok");
                        try
                        {
                            progressbar.ReleaseBar();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                        SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("ფაილის თარიღები არ ემთხვევა არჩეულ პერიოდს", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, true);
                        //cleanup
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                        //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
                        //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
                        //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

                        //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

                        //close and release
                        xlWorkbook.Close();
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

                        //quit and release
                        xlApp.Quit();
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //cleanup
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                    //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
                    //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
                    //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

                    //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

                    //close and release //

                    //xlWorkbook.Close();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);


                    //quit and release
                    //xlApp.Quit();
                    //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                }

            }
```

Comment: ORMs are *not* suitable for ETL jobs. They offer nothing at all in this scenario - there are no business entities or rules involved, just streams of data and transformations. Use SqlBulkCopy to import data into the database as fast as possible. Using Excel interop is extremely slow too. Use either the Jet OLEDB provider to read the Excel file or a library like EPPlus that can read Excel files directly. The Jet driver is the fastest though

Comment: Thanks Sir, Jet driver really helped me, now it only takes 1 minute to import each file!

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald I was using OLEDB with pleasure until my client got this error "System resource exceeded."  excel file is about 100kb and 2.2k rows. With same files it works great on my pc or any other pc in my office, can you advice me anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new Excel application object (xlApp) every time the loop circles - this will be slow. Try creating it before the loop so you can reuse it.

There may be other things you can do to speed it up, but I'm inclined to agree with Panagiotis' comment - don't use Interop here. I went down this rabbit hole too, and it is hugely more complicated and slower than using JET OLEDB.

Here is a rough guide to how you might use jet instead - I just fill a data table to use somewhere in the loop:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

foreach (var item in paths)
{
    string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + item + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

     using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
    {
        excelConnection.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        string query = sheetname.Contains(" ") ? string.Format("Select * from ['{0}$']", sheetname) : string.Format("Select * from [{0}$]", sheetname);
        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection))
        {
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        }

        //do something with the data here

        excelConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i switched to JET OLEDB and it really boosted performance.